# What is some math subject area that could widely apply to acturial science?

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

What is some math subject area that could widely apply to actuarial science?

I know that an actuary mainly deals with stochastic processes (stochastic calculus) / probabilty, statistics, calculus.

Comment: Look at the exam areas for more details: http://www.soa.org/education/exam-req/

Comment: You already mentioned stochastic calculus but does this include stochastic partial differential equations? Functional analysis is useful as well

Comment: What's the motivation for your question? It seems that you already know several areas which are applicable.

Comment: I think there are two somewhat separate questions: (1) What math do you need to know to pass the actuarial exams, and (2) what math do working actuaries actually use in their daily tasks. I expect that there is some overlap in the answers, but also some differences. I think question #2 needs to be answered by an actuary, not by a student or a teacher. Not sure which question(s) the OP is asking.

Comment: I am testing the waters as regards the viability of an actuarial Q&A site on Stack Exchange. Perhaps the contributors here wish to check it out at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60004/actuarial-science and provide feedback? I have already sprinkled the proposal with some questions not relating to the various actuarial qualifications and to the relevant exams, but the proposal does have capacity for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

calculus, probability theory, mathematical statistics, finance, economics, financial economics, and computer programming are just some of the fields related to actuary science

Comment: Speaking as an actuary (P/C), +1